# How to add a class to specific elements created with a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

I am creating a simple inventory "checker" which basically creates 14 divs that are either "active" or "inactive". With vue I create these divs with a simple v-for loop:

```
<div class="inventory">
 <div class="item" v-for="index in 14" :key="index" ></div>
</div>
```

Where I'm stuck is that I receive data from another source that provides me an array with numbers of the inventory items that are considered "active".

for example:

```
[{"id": "5","date": "2021-10-08 11:30:55"},{"id": "4","date": "2021-10-08 11:30:54"}]
```

**Note: the date tag is irrelevant for my question but it gives an idea how the object is looking for me. there is more data in it that is irrelevant for my question**

In this case that would mean I should give an "active" class to the 4th and 5th item in my inventory.
I don't see how I can loop through the (v-for looped) items to essentially add a if(inventoryId == id){addclass 'active'} to it. Any tips or nice vue tricks I could apply here? If anything is unclear please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the array from other source to be an array containing number of id, maybe something like this:

```
let otherSource = [{"id": "5","date": "2021-10-08 11:30:55"},{"id": "4","date": "2021-10-08 11:30:54"}]
// activeIds as a state/data
this.activeIds = otherSource.map(el => Number(el.id))
// activeIds as computed property
activeIds(){
   return otherSource.map(el => Number(el.id))
}
```

you can put activeIds as a state / computed property

and then

```
<div class="inventory">
  <div class="item" v-for="index in 14" :class="activeIds.includes(index) ? 'active' : 'inactive'" :key="index" ></div>
</div>
```

You can also put this part as computed property for better

```
activeIds.includes(index) ? 'active' : 'inactive'
```

I think this will do

Comment: Yes this did the trick! Interesting to use the ".include" function! One thing I had to add to make it work is to convert the this.activeIds array to integers. Since they are considered strings. Everything came out as "inactive" but after changing that it all worked perfectly! Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help!

Comment: I just had a talk with a colleague of mine and he showed me that its also possible like this. ":class="{'active':activeFlowerIds.includes(index)}" this will not add the "inactive" class to the element thought. But for this example that is no problem. Figured I shared it here for some extra example ^^